# Understanding a Magento Module

Tags: magento-1

I was working with PHP Core and custom MVCs by 1 and half years until when moved to magento desk.

I find it very difficult first, but later got grip in Theme integration and maintenance of previously done modules. Now I got in to Module creation and really confused with the architecture.

In frank, Everytime when I write a new code, It works well, but later edited out wasting so much time of seniors since It does not met completely with Magento's coding style.

For an example, when I need to check something and update a database, I writes,

```
<?php 
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$query = "SELECT ststus FROM table WHERE Id='".$id."'";
$select_query = $readConnection->fetchOne($query);
$update_value= $select_query[0];
if($update_value=='2')
{
$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$query = "UPDATE table SET field_name='C' WHERE Id='".$id."'";
$writeConnection->query($query);
}
?>
```

This is later changed to simply this,

```
foreach ($dealroomIds as $dealroomId) {
                $manufacturers = Mage::getSingleton('module/module')
                    ->load($dealroomId)
                    ->setStatus($this->getRequest()->getParam('status')); //getting status 
                    if($this->getRequest()->getParam('status')=='2'){
                    $manufacturers->setRunningStatus('C'); // setting new status
                    }
                $manufacturers->setIsMassupdate(true)
                    ->save();
                Mage::getSingleton('dealroom/deals')->UpdateDealProducts($dealroomId); // Update
                    }
```

The above given is just an example and nothing more than that.

To know more about the coding style and standard, I think is neccessory to know more about

- Block
- controllers
- Model
- Helper
- Data

I searched but whatever I read and understand is just far away from the basic. If anyone point out the connections and functions of these, it will be helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best practice? http://www.alanstorm.com, great blog that explains all the basics. I learned Magento this way :). Take a look at the creation of backend and frontend extensions!

Comment: btw if you have senior Magento devs, asking them for good tutorials or example extensions made by them would also help you alot ;)

Comment: Hehe you should thank Alan :D I'm just the messenger ^^

Answer (score 3):

A good start would be [Magento Developer Knowledge base articles](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento)
Then as mentioned, read Alan Storm's articles and watch [Fundamentals of Magento Development Video Course by Magento (Ben Marks)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/training/on-demand)

After that, I think, you should have a look at official [Extension's Developer Guide by Magento](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Magento-Extension-Developers-Guide-v1.0.pdf) - 80 pages on how-to create a custom extension (News) from scratch

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of useful and well written guide to create and understand module architecute.

Just to name a few :

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/

http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/